# Expose properties based on instance of a class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, dbcontext

I have a class as below:

```
public class UnitofWork<T> : IDisposable where T : DbContext, new(){
    private readonly T context = new T();
    private DbRepository<TypeA> _typeA;
    private DbRepository<TypeB> _typeB;

    public DbRepository<TypeA> TypeAProp
    {
        get
        {
            return _typeA ?? (_typeA= new DbRepository<TypeA>(context as SqlContext));
        }
    }

    public DbRepository<TypeB> TypeBProp
    {
        get
        {
            return _typeB ?? (_typeB= new DbRepository<TypeB>(context as OracleContext));
        }
    }
}
```

**SqlContext** and **OracleContext** are both children classes of DbContext.
TypeA & TypeB are auto generated entities by EF.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is that say that I create an instance of ClassA object..

```
var sqlDb = new UnitofWork<SqlContext>();
```

I do not want to expose the property TypeBProp for this instance of object. Same way if I create ClassA instance as below, I do not want to expose the TypeAProp.

```
var oracleDb = new UnitofWork<OracleContext>();
```

Is it at all even possible? 
Thanks in Advance!

- Johny

Comment: It might help a little if you replace `T`, `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `TypeA`, and `TypeB` with something meaningful. It makes the relationship between them unclear and maybe even suggests a relationship where none exists. It just adds a level of cognitive load (for me, anyway.)

Comment: @ScottHannen I'll try to be more descriptive - will edit the post.

Comment: You should only put on parent/base classes what is common to all derived classes.

Comment: You cannot have a class where some instances of the class expose a property and others don't. It's impossible. You could move the properties to more derived types. This sounds like an XY problem. There shouldn't be a reason for what you're trying to do. Why can't these be two different classes with their own properties? It's very likely that whatever you're trying to avoid doing is what you should be doing.

Comment: @ScottHannen I thought that too but i was curious if there's any way to accomplish this - was wondering perhaps generic implementation offers something like this ...

Comment: @ScottHannen basically these classes are unit of work / repo implementation - but instead of them working with one data connection there are 2 separate ones (one for SQL db and one for oracle) - So When i started coding the repository it was working perfectly with one data context but then when I started adding another one I thought I could make repo generic enough to work with both contexts - it works fine except exposing all properties. You're right it does sound like XY problem - but I was curious to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Oracle and SQL are different enough where you'd want different classes. You can still derive from a base, like this:

```
public class UnitofWork<T> : IDisposable where T : DbContext, new()
{
    //Same as you had it, but without TypeAProp and TypeBProp,
    //which we will add to the subclasses below
}

public class SqlServerUnitOfWork : UnitOfWork<SqlContext>
{
    protected DbRepository<TypeA> _typeA;

    public DbRepository<TypeA> TypeAProp
    {
        get
        {
            return _typeA;
        }
    }
}

public class OracleUnitOfWork : UnitOfWork<OracleContext>
{
    protected DbRepository<TypeB> _typeB;

    public DbRepository<TypeB> TypeBProp
    {
        get
        {
            return _typeB;
        }
    }
}
```

Call it with:

```
var sqlDb = new SqlServerUnitOfWork();
var a = sqlDb.TypeAProp;
var oracleDb = new OracleUnitOfWork();
var b = oracleDb.TypeBProp;
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem if if the parent class is supposed to contain the UoW methods sincz those depend onthe repository.

Comment: @JohnWu thank you for your post - i'm marking this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

`ClassA` clealry isn't generic.  For it to be generic it would need to be designed in order to function properly *regardless* of what type is provided as the generic argument.  Your type doesn't do that, it only actually supports two different types, and it needs to function differently depending on which of the two types of provided.

The solution there is to *have two classes*, one for the SQL version and one for the Oracle version, each with the members that are appropriate for their context.

Comment: That does make sense now - after reading some of the comments here. I edited to the post to be more descriptive.

Comment: @Johny has a unit of work that works with models. He should be able to make the unit of work generic.

Answer (score 1):

No, itsn't doable.

Once you the code is inside the class's brackets it is inside. It will expose all properties.

A solution might be :

```
public class UnitOfWork<T, CT> : IDisposable 
        where T : DbContext, new(){
    private readonly T context = new T();

    private DbRepository<CT> _type;

    public DbRepository<CT> Repository
    {
        get
        {
            return _type ?? (_type= new DbRepository<CT>(context);
        }
    }    

}
```

Following are some use cases:

```
var oraclePersonUoW = new UnitOfWork<OracleContext, Person>();
var oracleBookUoW = new UnitOfWork<OracleContext, Book>();
var sqlPersonUoW = new UnitOfWork<SqlContext, Person>();
var sqlBookUoW = new UnitOfWork<SqlContext, Book>();
```

Comment: "If TypeA and TypeB are in the same inheritance tree" unfortunately not. TypeA and TypeB both belong to 2 separate EF entities (Sql & Oracle - as i'm dealing with 2 data connections)

Comment: Try my solution without the clause on the second generic parameter on ClassA.
I have edited my answer with an example, check it.

Comment: You mean not having where PropType : TypesBaseClassOrSharedContract ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that there are many such 'types' not just one per context.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem.
In fact, you can leave the unit of work open and close it only on instantiation.
I am going to re-edit my answer in light of your last comment. Since I understand your requirements better now

Comment: But that would require me to pass type each time i create an instance of unit of work... like say I have 10 types (models) for SqlContext - I'd have to instantiate new UnitOfWork<SqlContext , TypeC>())

Comment: Yes, of course. 

The thing is, the unit of work being generic, means you would need to close it at some point before running the application.

My solution actually is less code. Instead, of having one class/file per model you will only have the generic UoW and you close it on each instantiation.

Comment: The problem with this is when I'm performing operations on multiple entities eg: oraclePersonUoW.SomeOperation requires updating oracleBookUoW i'd have to create another instance just to do so... What i'm looking to do is have one instance that works with all entities - which is how I had it before oracle came in... :-/ Did you see John Wu's suggestion?

Comment: You could do something like what Micosoft does with tuples https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What solution did you go for?

Comment: Not a fan of working with tuples to be honest. I went with John Wu's solution - it works perfectly with the rest of my WCF app structure for example. Thank you for all your time and effort - def learned some new things from this convo! Cheers

Comment: I actually ended up not taking John Wu's approach - I like it but theres another way to make Repo and unit of work both generic enough to work with both Models - I did use your approach but in a slightly different manner.  I'll add that as an answer as this comment section is getting bigger.